# How to delete space-dots between words in Sublime Text 3?

Tags: sublimetext3

[image]

How to remove the dots marked in red in the screenshot?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Go to Preferences - Settings - User and add

```
{
    "draw_white_space": "none"
}
```